# Vertical bias and guidlines are not working in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I want to use vertical bias to view always top but, I want to use guidelines to restrict the height on the screen. But If I used height wrap content it's not working until I set it to height 0dp. Does any better approach for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recylerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guidelines"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

After adding @Ivo answer

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but the problem is my last view is cutting

[image]

Comment: What's exactly wrong now? I assume it's now cut off at the guideline or not? isn't that exactly what you wanted? or how do you expect it to work?

Comment: @IvoBeckers my recylerview going below the guidline. I don't want to go view outside of guidline and i want default height to wrap

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I completely understand it but I think you actually want `android:orientation="horizontal"` instead of `android:orientation="vertical"` in your Guideline

EDIT:

try using 0dp and also adding `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` to your recyclerview

Comment: How can i restricted recyclerview height if i used horizontal in guidelines ?

Comment: a guideline is a line. you want your recyclerview to be above the line. so the line goes from left to right. So it's a horizontal line

Comment: you are right I updated the code.

Comment: but main problem is If i set recylerview height to 0dp it restrict the line. But if i used wrap content it's not working. I want mostly the recyclerview top of screen.

Comment: is there a problem with using 0dp?

Comment: yes, For example If my item is one or two I want to show in top of screen.  if item more than 5 than I want to show full recyclerview untill Guidelines .

Comment: ah ok. now I understand

Comment: @vivekmodi see my edit

Comment: is there any better suggestion? I tried with vertical bias alone its not working. I asked in other [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69700522/11560810) but I didn't get it

Comment: I updated my answer, the problem is view is going outside of guideline

Comment: is there any other solution to fix that?